# ORACLE: Explain Plan for insert

Tags: sql, oracle, explain, sql-execution-plan

I wonder why the value is not inserted in the table, when I execute the following statement. Is that correct? And is it possible to insert the value and watching the explain plan?

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR INSERT INTO TABLE values(5);
```

Comment: @LeorA: whether they commit or not is irrelevant.

Comment: Correct, I thought he was doing the insert separately, and was showing the explain plan also.

Answer (score 4):

The value is not inserted because you are running an explain query.  If you want to insert the record, run this insert query.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE values(5);
```

Depending on where you are running that command from, you may have to run a commit query afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

This will do exactly what you wanted (*insert the value and watching the explain plan*)...

```
SET AUTOTRACE ON
INSERT INTO myTABLE values(5);
SET AUTOTRACE OFF
```